# Tizen emulator wearable web app styles not working

Tags: css, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I have a problem with the Tizen emulators. I have set up Tizen studio and run a sample app. for the targeted devices, styles applied well. below is a target device screenshot.

[image]

but unfortunately for Tizen emulators styles not working. please refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

I can't understand why this happens. here is my code and it is just a simple one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
    <!-- load theme file for your application -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">
        <div class="ui-header">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-content">
            <p>Hello TAU!</p>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-footer">
            <button>OK</button>
         </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
    <script src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help me, appreciate their support. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer was received from the Samsung developer forum.

```
I never use the newer watch emulators they are always buggy.

Try the W-4.0 Wearable-Circle-x86 Emulator to see if that works correctly.

Ron
```

Now it working perfectly!